# Converting a jQuery function that increments a counter if scrolled past an element to vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert a function that increments a counter once the user scrolls past a section element, i got most of it working but somehow the increment goes nuts after i pass the first section element, is my function to determine the offset to top of each element total wrong?

i also figured that the vanilla JS version outputs slightly different pixels compared to the jQuery solution.

jQuery:
[codePen](http://codepen.io/HendrikEng/pen/LyNpzd?editors=0011)

```
// scoll to next section and back to top
var $scrollSection = $('section');
var $scrollTrigger = $('.section_trigger');
var nextSection = 0;

// turn arrow when scrolled to footer
$(window).scroll(function() {

  //console.log('current distance to top ' +  $('body').scrollTop());
  //console.log('element distance to top ' + $($scrollSection[nextSection]).offset().top);

  while ($('body').scrollTop() > $($scrollSection[nextSection]).offset().top) {
      nextSection++;
      console.log('current section' + nextSection);
  }     
});
```

JS:
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/HendrikEng/pen/OmNNzv?editors=0011)

```
const sectionElements = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
const scrollTrigger = document.querySelector('.section_trigger');
let nextSection = 0;
let scrollObject = {};
const element = sectionElements[nextSection];

// calculate an elements distance to top 
const elemRect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
      offset   = elemRect.top - document.body.scrollTop;

// function to get the current distance to top
window.onscroll = getScrollPosition;

function getScrollPosition(){
    scrollObject = {
       x: window.pageXOffset,
       y: window.pageYOffset
    }
}


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

// console.log('current distance to top ' + scrollObject.y);
// console.log('element distance to top ' + offset);

 if (scrollObject.y > offset) { 
    nextSection += 1;
    console.log('current section' + nextSection);
  }

});
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmNzOg?editors=0011)

```
const sectionElements = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
const scrollTrigger = document.querySelector('.section_trigger');
let nextSection = 0;
let scrollObject = {};

// function to get the current distance to top
window.onscroll = getScrollPosition;

function getScrollPosition(){
    scrollObject = {
       x: window.pageXOffset,
       y: window.pageYOffset
    }
}


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let element = sectionElements[nextSection];

  // calculate an elements distance to top 
  let elemRect    = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  let offset = document.body.scrollTop + elemRect.top;

// console.log('current distance to top ' + scrollObject.y);
// console.log('element distance to top ' + offset);

 if (scrollObject.y > offset) {
    nextSection += 1;
    console.log('current section' + nextSection);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply...ahh i should have placed the element in the function...it almost works, only difference to the jqery version is that it should increment once the current section leaves the viewport, now it increments to the section once it enters the viewport

Comment: Glad I helped :)